# Run window manager with chromium and go through proxy server on RPI

Tags: proxy, raspberry-pi, chromium

I am using Raspberry pi(s) for workstations in an office setup. I want the users to have access to the intranet and a couple of websites. I have a proxy set up with whitelist that works fine.

I want to boot the RPI and show only a web browser and connect through the proxy. I understand I need a window manager for this.

I have been experimenting with chromium (as it makes it very easy to insert the proxy address as an attribute when opening chromium via command line). The problem is, Chromium is a demanding browser and struggles with JQuery on the RPI.

I am looking for a browser I can run through a proxy, in a window manager from a start up script that won't be slow as hell!

Does this exist? Or am I going down the wrong path for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is really what you want but here is one way to boot directly into a web-browser:
1. Make sure you use a Raspberry with the latest version of raspbian installed and updated:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

2. If you don't want to use Midori, install the browser you want. I prefer chromium (Light version of Google Chrome) so that's what I will use here. To install chromium run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium
```

3. Configure raspi-config to start in GUI mode:

```
sudo raspi-config -> Enable boot to desktop/Scratch -> Desktop login as....
```

4. To start chromium on boot, comment all existing code in the file and add the following last:

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@chromium
```

On the last line you can also add switches like `kiosk mode (--kiosk)` after `@chromium`. Watch this link for more switches:
[List of commandline switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Hope this was any help! Good luck!